# Google Apps Script Test Deployment on multiple documents

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, google-docs

I am building a Google Docs Add-on using Google Apps Script, and that add-on does different things in different documents.
I obviously can't test it in a regular deployment (users are using it while I'm developing), so test deployments are probably the way to go, except when trying to create one it does not let me pick more than one document to use the test deployment.

Is there a workaround / something I missed which would allow me to test my add-on in multiple documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation that explains [how to test an Editor Add on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons) this is not something possible, the recommended way is to select 'No Document Selected' as this will generate a test document where you can start testing on. I won't recommend testing the add-on while still being developed on multiple documents as a good practice but take it with a grain of salt.